# Direct link to app-store application in iOS 7

Tags: ios, app-store, ios7

I have a free version of app. And there is a link to a full version in free app.
The link works fine in iOS 6. But in iOS 7 it shows a blank page.
Any help is appreciated!

The link I use:

```
- (void) getFull
{
    [self hideAnimated];
    NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=604760686&mt=8";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pretty strange link you are using. I use:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id<APP_ID>?mt=8
```

and everything works...

In apps supporting iOS6 and above, I suggest furthermore the use of StoreKit, so you can display your app page in the App Store without leaving your app. You can do that like this:

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController
{
   [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)showAppWithIdentifier:(NSNumber *)identifier
{

  if ([SKStoreProductViewController class]) {
     SKStoreProductViewController *controller = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
     controller.delegate = self;
     [controller loadProductWithParameters:@{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : identifier }
                          completionBlock:NULL];

     [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
     return;
   }

    // Fall back to opening App Store for iOS 5.
    ... open the link as you are already doing
}
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work either. In iOS 6 it says that my product is not available in Russian App Store. In iOS 7 it shows blank page. Will check the StoreKit later.

Comment: I have just tried the link I suggested with your app id (http://itunes.apple.com/app/id604760686&mt=8) and it works just fine on iOS7... sorry, I now realize I forgot to put the "id" at the beginning of <APP_ID> in my answer... edited

Comment: identifier should be a NSNumber, not NSString

Comment: @CocoaPriest: thanks, I edited my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one, it's the new syntax with iOS 7 and replace APP_ID by your application's AppID.

`itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idAPP_ID`

You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/issues/109) and [this one](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/pull/132) for more information and discussion about that.