# killing iPhone app due to wrong version

Tags: ios

I would like to show an alert to users that they must update the app if their version is no longer supported and kill the application, I've read in here many answers saying that using exit(0) or [[NSThread mainThread] exit] may cause my app to be refused in the app-store for non-standard interface.

I have several application that have this feature so I'm wondering what is the right way to achieve the above task

```
if ([requiredVersion compare:actualVersion options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
{// actualVersion is lower than the requiredVersion
    ???
}
```

Comment: in your alert message have an action button/link that takes the user straight to your new app in the App Store.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067892/direct-link-to-app-store-application-in-ios-7, you don't really need to exit your app, that is non-standard behavior

Comment: @CSmith I've used your suggestion my problem now is that by clicking cancel at the store the app still run and is functional - and I wish to block the user from using it until s/he upgrades

Comment: Make your alert a MODAL view controller, and the link to the App Store the only option for your user.  i.e. create a dead-end in your app

Comment: @CSmith can you please help me with the code? I've created the alert that responds to the button click but again once i return from the store the flow continues - right now i've done an ugly unfriendly patch and place the if in the viewdidload as well as viewdidapear which means the alert and store will open time and time again --> cause frustration to users and is anoying

Answer (score 0):

If your app uses the Crashlytics crash logging service, you can use a function they provide for this purpose.

```
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];
```

Keep in mind that killing your own app is generally frowned upon, etc.